# Infinity build on netlify

Tags: javascript, node.js, bots

I'm coding a whatsapp bot, and his working properly, when a put on netlify, it's work, but the problem is after i scan the QR code to login, it show the message of "Client is ready!", but the build still happend, what should i do to solve this ?

```
const client = new Client({
    authStrategy: new LocalAuth()
})

client.on('qr', qr => {
    qrcode.generate(qr, {small: true})
})


client.on('ready', () => {
    console.log('Client is ready!');
})
```

it show the message "Client is ready!" and the bot works, but i can keep the process running as "building"